# How do you encode the POST request for an OAuth 2.0 request for a token?

Tags: character-encoding, oauth

I've been reading the OAuth spec and trying to comb through examples but the exact process to this is not clear =/

how to create the URL request string...

Answer (score 1):

[Section 9.1 of the OAuth 1.0a spec](http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#signing_process) explains this quite clearly.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about which part you don't understand.

Comment: The encoding part, how to create the URL request string

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "URL request string".